# import css as a string (vue-cli)

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-style-loader, vue-cli

At first, I created a clear project `vue create project` from `vue-cli last version`

In `main.js` I tried to import styles from `'./test.css'`, in my `test.css` I have two classes.

In `console.log(styles)` or `console.log(styles.className)` I found `empty object` or `undefined`, why did this happen?

BTW, `styles.toString()` doesn't work, in `vue-cli` doc I found https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules but it doesn't work too.

I also found such a construction for writing:

```
var myStyle = require('./test.css');
myStyle.use(); //inject it via a `<style>` element
myStyle.unuse(); //removes it
```

http://tomasalabes.me/blog/web-development/2016/09/13/Webpack-Series-Part-4.html

But it also doesn't work...

Maybe I am doing something wrong? Sorry for this, but can someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save-dev raw-loader`

```js
const styles = require('!!raw-loader!../public/file.css');

// object
console.log(styles);

// string of original file
console.log(styles.default);
```